# Can't delete folder from fileshare

Tags: windows-server-2012, ntfs

I'd like to start with saying that my knowledge is kind of basic with the windows file system and how it works with permissions etc. I'm a SQL dba and i'm facing an issue which I think has to do with NTFS permissions or settings.

#### A little background

We have a replication server that creates snapshots that are put in different folders on a file share. Clients will then connect to this file share and download their snapshot.

#### The issue

To create these snapshots we have a job running on de SQL server (Running under a domain account) to refresh these snapshot folders. It should delete the current snapshot folder and create a new one with updated data.

What currently happens is that SQL is somehow not able to delete this folder

```
Message: Could not remove directory 
'\\FILESERVER\VTWSnapshot\unc\SERVERNAME$DEV05_DATABASENAME\41_9\'.
Check the security context of xp_cmdshell and close other processes
that may be accessing the directory.
```

We gave the replication account full control on the folder (This account creates the folders) and we also gave the SQL Service account full control. We asked the server admin to capture all windows event while we executed the job and it seems the SQL Service account attempts to delete the folder but fails. It is local admin and has full control on the file share folder. 
Is there anything we're missing?

Since everything server-related is done from America, we have a 6 hour difference between me and the server admins. So I'd love to get as much suggestions as possible so we can set up a meeting and try a few different things at once.
So any suggestions are welcome.

#### Edit

We also checked if another program was using/locking any of the files in the folder, this wasn't the case.

#### Edit 2

Been playing around a little and I noticed that when I try to delete a folder that somebody else created, I get this message.

[image: Require permissions before delete]

Cloud it be that the delete statement from the job is getting blocked by this?
The procedure attempts to delete the folder using this command:

```
rmdir /S /Q
```

Since both accounts have Full control, it should be able to delete the folder.

Comment: There could be a program/service using a file in the folder or the folder itself and that's prohibiting you from deletion.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that in my post, we checked that. There is no other program using any of the files in the folder. I'll add that to the post.